# Can't keep new user logged in with omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

The first time the User is created but it doesn't keep me logged in, even if I set **sign_in @user** after creating the Customer, the next time I access it does sign me in.

Am I missing something?

```
class CallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if resource.id.blank?
       sign_in resource, event: :authentication 
       set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: 'Facebook') if is_navigational_format?
       # Create customer
       Customer.create(:user_id => resource.id, :name => resource.name, :lastname => resource.lastname)

       redirect_to new_user_session_path 
    else
       sign_in resource_name, resource
       redirect_to profile_path
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So I had to add

```
session["warden.user.user.key"][0] = resource.id
```

for a weird reason it wasn't adding the ID from the user to the session.

This worked for me but I don't think is the "way" to do it.